# How to make many2one field auto-complete in Odoo(formerly openerp)?

Tags: autocomplete, odoo, many-to-one

We have partner_id field in sale order form, I want to make that field auto-complete when user going to input the value, any suggestions will be welcome.

my code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="air_odoo_sale_order_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">air.odoo.sale.order.view</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <field name="partner_id" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="group">base.group_manager,base.group_sale_salesman</attribute>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
   </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: many2one field is by default auto complete? what is your extra need?

Comment: can you please edit your question wih python & xml code? I am still confuse what you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you, because I am new to odoo, i don't know this is a auto-complete field, due to the bug in overridden name_search it is not work, after removing this bug it is working now.

Comment: ah.! name_search method can be use for extending m2o field search.